# meta-java error while building yocto image

Tags: java, yocto, bitbake

I have included meta-java in the yocto build.

while bitbake, I am getting below error.

```
r@r-VirtualBox:~/prj/build$ bitbake iot-eval-image
WARNING: /home/r/prj/sources/meta-java/recipes-core/openjdk/openjre-8_16xbyy.bb: Exception during build_dependencies for do_unpack_remove_X11_wrappers                             | ETA:  --:--:--
WARNING: /home/r/prj/sources/meta-java/recipes-core/openjdk/openjre-8_16xbyy.bb: Error during finalise of /home/r/prj/sources/meta-java/recipes-core/openjdk/openjre-8_16xbyy.bb
ERROR: Unable to parse /home/r/prj/sources/meta-java/recipes-core/openjdk/openjre-8_16xbyy.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I am not able to proceed.
Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us the full log and make sure you're using compatible layers

Comment: Hii.. I used the latest meta-java and tried again. Now bitbake is successful. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this example

with or without docker

https://github.com/452/yocto-embedded-java